Amplify - Next JS 14. I can't see the console.log on the server side
I have recently deployed an application in NextJS 14 on AWS-Amplify (Gen 2).
My next.config.js file is as follows:
/** @type {import('next').NextConfig} */
const nextConfig = {
    reactStrictMode: false,
    images: {
      remotePatterns: [
        { protocol: 'https',
          hostname: 'static.cdn.com'
        }
      ]
    },
    output: 'standalone'
}

module.exports = nextConfig

And the configuration in amplify to deploy is:
version: 1
frontend:
  phases:
    preBuild:
      commands:
        - npm ci --cache .npm --prefer-offline
    build:
      commands:
        - env | grep -e NEXT_PUBLIC_ >> .env.production
        - npm run build
  artifacts:
    baseDirectory: .next
    files:
      - '**/*'
  cache:
    paths:
      - .next/cache/**/*
      - .npm/**/*

I have noticed that the APIs that are executed on the client side work normally and show the logs in the browser.However, the logs I have on the server side are not shown in CloudWatch. It only shows the following:

And it seems strange to me since I can't verify if the APIs I have are actually being executed on the server side.
This is an example of my code for fetch some URL in a component:
const data = await (
   await fetch(
     `${process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_BASE_URL}/api/auth`,
     { method: "POST", headers: { ... }, body: { ... } }
   )
).json();
token = data.Token || "";
console.log("Hello Token: ", token);

Is there a way to check if the APIs are being executed on the server side? And see the console.log? Or is there something I'm doing wrong in my deployment?

im running into the same issue, did you figure out how to do it?

In the past I couldn't see the logs it posted on the server side.
However, I noticed that within Cloudwatch it generates 2 logs, one without the console.logs and another with them.
Anyone who has this problem should check if 2 logs appear at the same time (hh:mm) and search between those 2 where their logs are.
